# Broken HTML table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following styling and HTML, but when it displays, the table appears broken (all the table rows and cells are broken). I'm not sure why; how can I fix it?

```css
tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 130px);
}

tbody > tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-8 ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <option value="" selected=""></option>
                  <option value="-action"> Action</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <option value="" selected=""></option>
                  <option value="-action"> Action</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <option value="" selected=""></option>
                  <option value="-action"> Action</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--  textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="textarea"></label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <compose view="./-box.html"></compose>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "broken". Looks fine here https://www.bootply.com/TGbTTHQDhs

Comment: why have you set `tbody` to `display: block` and `tr` to `display: table;`?
 https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/9/

Comment: @j08691 You didn't include the css that's in the fiddle & OP which is why the bootply is ok- basically, remove the display props and you're good to go

Comment: thank you, but  the tbody need have a scroll understand?  the thead need be fixed because it is a small space, this table will have 100000 lines so the table need have a scroll right now the table is breaking. so I need the tbody have this size I defined cant be more than the red line, can you udnerstand? I need have scroll in the tbody: https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `tbody` has a `display: block` set to it and your `tr` has a `display: table`. Something in your css must be setting this. You can remove whatever is setting this or override it by adding the following to your css.

```css
tbody {
    display:block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
}

tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

tbody > tr {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-8 ">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="">
        <thead>
            <th>test</th>
            <th>test</th>
            <th>test</th>
            <th>test</th>
            <th>test</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="" >
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <option value="" selected=""></option>
                  <option value="-action"> Action</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="" >
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <option value="" selected=""></option>
                  <option value="-action"> Action</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="" >
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <option value="" selected=""></option>
                  <option value="-action"> Action</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--  textarea -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="textarea"></label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <compose view="./-box.html"></compose>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you, but  the tbody need have a scroll understand?  the thead need be fixed because it is a small space, this table will have 100000 lines so the table need have a scroll right now the table is breaking. so I need the tbody have this size I defined cant be more than the red line, can you udnerstand? I need have scroll in the tbody: https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/11/

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

remove display property in both tbody and tr

```
tbody {
   //display:block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
}

tbody > tr {
  //display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but  the tbody need have a scroll understand?  the thead need be fixed because it is a small space, this table will have 100000 lines so the table need have a scroll right now the table is breaking.